# Weird SQL Connective Issue w/Win 2012 Server

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-server-2012

Background:

- There are two 2014 SQL servers..   A1   and B2.
- There are three other 2012 servers(S1,S2,S3).. and some Win7 boxes

**Issues:**
The S1 Win2012 can see both A1 and B2 Sql Servers.   But when trying to connectthrough ODBC process.. can NOT connect to A1 Sql Server.   ***Connects just fine to Sql B2 though.***
Other facts:

- Win 2012 S2  can connect and see A1 and B2
- Win 2012 S3  can connect and see A1 and B2.
- All Win7 machines can connect and see Sql A1 and B2

Why does Win2012 S1 - have an issue with SQL A1 ??  It can see it (assuming through SQL Browser), but can't connect.  When trying to connect to get the 'SQLStat='HYT00'  - Error locating Server Instance.

I am at a loss.  Can't be firewall issue on S1 - otherwise it couldn't connect to the B2 SQL server.   Can't be an issue with the A1 SQL server itself (or so I think.. ) because every other machine can connect to A1 just fine too.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: It does sound like a firewall issue even though you say it cannot.. A incoming port, from S1 could be blocked on A1 (for example). Firewalls have many complicated settings. Do you have any SQL Alias in your SQL Server Configuration Manager that is pointed incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to tcping 1433 port from S1 to A1, then try to check communication by using Microsoft Network Monitor or a network sniffer tool in moment when you trying to connect to server.
 In some cases you can have different routes between servers, if you are using glbp and have different acl's on each node in glbp group. So try to traceroute form S1 to A1 then from S2 to A2.
 Ensure you have allowed incoming 1433 port on A1 server and he didn't have disallowed rules for ip or DNS name for your S1 server.

this ref. might be helpful https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287932